# What does MediaStore.Images.Media.MINI_THUMB_MAGIC do?

Tags: android, mediastore

I was just curious about what the MediaStore.Images.Media.MINI_THUMB_MAGIC column contains. Does it have anything to do with the image's thumbnail? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html) from the Android developers ref. for the doc -- which says it returns "the mini thumb id".

Also see [Displaying Thumbnail Photos on Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013176/displaying-photo-thumbnails-on-map) for how to use this ID:

```
long thumbId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MINI_THUMB_MAGIC));
String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(thumbId)};
Cursor ct = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + "= ?", args, null);
```

Comment: What would you do with the thumbId after this code? wouldn't you prefer to use Thumbnails.getThumbnail(...) instead ?

Comment: The MediaStore is really powerful, but it lacks real documentation ;/

Answer (score 1):

`MINI_THUMB_MAGIC` returns a random number and you can not get thumbnail id from this. Use `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID`, it is the same number as `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID`

```
ArrayList<String> ids; // ArrayList of MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", ids) + ")";
Cursor cursor2 = resolver.query(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{{MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID}},
                        selection,
                        null,
                        null);
```